# Which is the best php framework to start with?

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii, laravel

It is the first time i am going to use any php framework and i am confused among **zend framework, yii & Laravel**. Also which one has better community.

Comment: Which is the best: an apple, an orange or a pineapple?

Comment: Sorry but: *As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*

Comment: @GBD: the worst code of these 3 though

Comment: You're a spammer and so is your accomplice that answered this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned Yii and Laravel v4. In my opinion only 2 good.

Yii - Really good and old framework with many ready libraries.

Laravel 4 - new framework, better then yii, new modern and best solutions there. But there is not many ready libraries yet.

I moved to Laravel 4, beucase i believe it is the best framework for this day. It is easy and elegant.

If i were you, i will learn one of this two what i wrote. Because i choose Laravel 4 after learned Yii, i recommend Laravel.

Comment: actually i am also considering Laravel 4

Comment: Visit http://four.laravel.com/ and start learn :) Also join to irc #laravel.

Comment: This answer is complete bs. @kabra and the questioner are obviously spamming to promote Laravel.

Comment: I would disagree with the above commenter. The answer may be opinionated, but the two frameworks mentioned are the fastest growing frameworks.

Answer (score 7):

Choosing a framework will not depend upon the **popularity of the framework** or something else,it totally depend upon **our project requirements**.

For that we need to go through features of different frameworks providing for us,then finally it will be in our hand's to choose the frameworks keeping above points in mind.

I'm using [KOHANA 2.x](http://docs.kohanaphp.com//contents) for my project, it have almost all the features for modern web development.

Answer (score 1):

Its very much about personal preference and the scope of your project. Zend will make you a better developer, it's very well written. Albeit hard to learn if your new to frameworks, but good documentation, support, community etc even commercial support, if u want it, from the people who made PHP

Answer (score 0):

I've used several, and many are good, but from my experience with 6 or 7 frameworks, [cakephp](http://cakephp.org/) is the easiest, with Yii probably being the fastest performance-wise.  Cake is an all around good framework.